# iOS application transfer

Tags: ios, transfer

I have the following question.
When I received application transfer request and tried to Confirm it I faced some errors:

```
The following error(s) occurred:
You must enter a phone number in the App Store Contact Information section.
You must provide a first name in the App Store Contact Information section.
You must provide a last name in the App Store Contact Information section.
You must provide an email address in a valid format (for example, support@example.com) in the App Store Contact Information section .
```

Does anyone know where I should fill this data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Having exactly the same issue and don't know where is this "App Store Contact Information section"

Comment: a good question, I have the same issue!

Comment: Same for me. Must be a bug with the latest ITC release. Give it a day or two and all will be fine (and maybe report a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Having the same problem here! Hope they fix it soon, becuase we want to transfer our apps to our knew developer account before our old expires (today!).

Comment: Also having the same problem.  I got an account expiring on Friday lol.

Comment: Apple is aware of the issue, and are working on fixing it.  You should call them and let them open up a ticket for support for you.  Also, if you are expiring soon, you can request an extension.  They will honor an extension as long as you have the info for the sending developer account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 1):

Apple has resolved the problem.  You can accept the transfers now.